# How do I force a test method to run by itself?

Tags: java, testng

I have a TestNG test that loads hundreds of items into a system and verifies that the correct number have been saved.

There is potential test leakage though as I have other test methods in the test class that load items into the system as well.

I currently have to put `dependsOnMethods = "testBulkLoad"` on every other test method in this class to keep them separate. However, they aren't dependent on each other and I don't want this bulk load running when I run the other tests by themselves.

Is it possible to force this method to run by itself so that no other tests in this class run at the same time and potentially add items to the system and affect the count?

**NB:** There is a large setup time involved in intialising these tests which is why they aren't separated out into different classes.

Comment: Maybe use a [ReadWriteLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html) where the batch test acquires a write lock and the other tests acquire a read lock?

Comment: Or just disable parallel test execution?

Comment: Are you loading these items into a database? What's taking a long time to initialize - the DB? Docker?

Comment: Its a blockchain system that starts an in-memory instance bootstrapping itself that takes about 90s to start. There are other quicker tests in the project though using mocks but these ones in question are closer to integration tests.

Comment: Create a proxy method to the database and let every connection pass through it. You can then easily control its behavior by using locks.